# Is it possible to have both ion cube and zend loaders running on the same server?

Tags: php, web-server, zend, ioncube

For ion cube I need this line

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so
```

while for zend I need this one

```
zend_extension = /etc/php5/ZendOptimizer.so
```

Are these loaders mutually exclusive and if no, what line do I need to have them both running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the two lines together (in this order) seem to work fine

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so
zend_extension = /etc/php5/ZendOptimizer.so
```